# Twitter Bootstrap is not working with Visualforce

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, visualforce

i am trying to use Bootstrap with Visualforce .i created appropriate static resources but its not showing twitter bootstrap behaviour .can any one please tell why ?? here is the procedure how i am trying to integrate  first i added Bootstrap directory and named this bootstrap as a static resource then i uploaded latest jQUery.js file and named this JQUery1 resource

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" controller="hello11">

  <head>
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.JQUery1}"/>

<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css')}"/>

<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.bootstrap, 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js')}"/>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
   <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    Fluid 12
    <div class="row-fluid">
      <div class="span6">
        Fluid 6
        <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
          <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span6">Fluid 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</apex:page>
```

instead of getting bootstrap effects i am getting screen below 
[image]
as you can see there is no error in console means all resources are loaded correctly now the doubt is why it is not showing fluid effects can any one please describe why i am not getting fluid effects??

Comment: I assume you meant "Twitter Bootstrap is not working with Visualforce" in title.

Comment: sorry yes you got it right thanks for correction

Answer (score 2):

It seems that stylesheet file is not loaded correctly, can you check "Network" tab? Click there and reload page, you will see if some HTTP request returns "Not found" (404) error code. Then you just should check your paths.

Comment: no i am getting 200 for every request in networks .i think is the added css file is sufficient or should i add some other css because when i am running same code using html on my local machine still i am not getting the fluids effects